# StyleGAN 2 multiplies loss components with zero, why?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, loss

I found a rather odd piece of code in a 3.8k star repo of the well known StyleGAN 2 paper.

In the loss function they use the [following expression](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/blob/d72cc7d041b42ec8e806021a205ed9349f87c6a4/training/loss.py#L130C1-L132C1):

```
with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function(name + '_backward'):
    (real_logits * 0 + loss_Dreal + loss_Dr1).mean().mul(gain).backward()
```

(They use something similar in [line 92](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/blob/d72cc7d041b42ec8e806021a205ed9349f87c6a4/training/loss.py#L92))

Multiplying `real_logits` with `0` seems to me like unnecessary computation overhead. However, the same code is adapted by other researches like the authors of "MAT: Mask-Aware Transformer for Large Hole Image Inpainting". See [here](https://github.com/fenglinglwb/MAT/blob/d273d891ecdad2e1df106516423a75bc45b2d800/losses/loss.py#L168):

```
with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function(name + '_backward'):
    ((real_logits + real_logits_stg1) * 0 + loss_Dreal + loss_Dreal_stg1 + loss_Dr1 + loss_Dr1_stg1).mean().mul(gain).backward()
```

The only hypothesis that I have is that they want a quick way of initializing a matrix of a specific shape filled with zeros. However, this makes no sense as everything ends up in the `mean()` anyways.

What other purpose does this fulfill?

Comment: The `.backwards()` is probably not callable, if you created the tensor from zeros. multiplying with zero maybe keeps that intact?

Comment: the scalar output is the very same when omitting the zero term. But there must be a clever side effect during back propagation :-/